# Correcting polygon geometry so edges can be reshaped to match that of subsequent layer in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, polygon, editing, maritime-map

I have two layers; a polygon layer representing maritime boundaries/economic areas of countries in the world and another polygon layer representing all countries but with a detailed coastline. In the image, you can see that the economic boundary (red) has been simplified at the coast. I would like to correct this on a global scale so the detailed coastline replaces the simplified edge.

[image]

Is there a quick way to do this manually or maybe via Python or ModelBuilder?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

Comment: If you have the Advanced (old term ArcInfo) you might see if you can convert your polygons to lines and points, then delete the unwanted simplified lines, copy in the the correct ones, and then build polygons using the points to get back the attributes.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of the relationship/form of your rough polygons (ie where things overlap and how, what are 'holes'), but it seems you could just extract the polygons with those 'oceanic' boundary lines and then incorporate them into the detailed file via an intersect or union (again, depends on what is and isn't a hole). There's also the Replace Geometry command. And integrate/snap, but I wouldn't consider those for something this complex.